# can not edit in pg_ident.conf

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

how to make pg_ident.conf easy accessible and edit on it.

any suggestion ?!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50595/can-not-edit-in-pg_ident.conf/) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-12-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot edit this file because this file belongs to user postgres, you didn't have privilege to edit this file.This can be verified by using

```
ls -l /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_ident.conf
```

You can edit this file in two ways.

1.Change to user postgres

```
sudo su - postgres
```

Then edit the file by

```
vim /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_ident.conf
```

2.Use root privilege to edit the file

```
sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_ident.conf
```

If you didn't have vim installed yet, use

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Once you enter vim editor, press "i" to become INSERT mode, and you can edit the file. When you finished editing, type ":wq" to save the file and leave vim editor.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-02-26**:
I have the same question of @Amal and when I tried to be a user postgres , a password for postgres was requested !

@Ricky

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2013-03-01**:
When you type `sudo su - postgres` to become user postgres, the password you need is your original user's.

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-02**:
yes, I have tried my original password ant it worked , but I have stopped at the step of making an administrator of my created database using pgadmin , There was an error that the version of pgadmin isn't suitable to the version of the postgreSQL.